# how to simulate pressing an arrow key in linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've worked with powershell before but I'm new to linux bash scripts. Say I wanted to write a script that just presses a key (left arrow) in regular intervals (0.05s). How could I go about doing this?

Comment: How? In a graphical interface of some kind, such as X? In a program that's being spawned as a subprocess? Bash doesn't have an inherent concept of any of these things -- it doesn't understand GUI toolkits -- so you're going to need to be very, very specific, since this will require using external tools specific to the details of your use case.

Comment: ...that is, an answer for X11 will be different from an answer for something running in a TTY emulator such as `screen` or `tmux` will be different from an answer for Windows will be different from an answer for an embedded UI toolkit such as Qt/E or Gtk/E... etc. (I've actually done input emulation for those last two, but it required a kernel module adding support for synthesizing evdev events).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [Xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/). Its usage is:

```
xdotool key SPECIFY_KEY
```

and replace SPECIFY_KEY with the required keystroke,

or in **your** case:

```
xdotool key Up/Down/etc.
```

Comment: Thanks that should work for my scipt. I was having a hard time finding a list of all key codes and I thought it would be like Left_Arrow or soemthing. Do you know what this means though: ^[[A I always see stuff like this show up in the terminal and it did when I ran this command from the terminal instead of a script.

Comment: @Deoxal: That's an escape code for the up button. Terminals only accepts ascii as input, so when your terminal emulator receives other input, like an arrow key, it encodes it into ASCII using escape sequences like that one, which are then interpreted appropriately. For some reason, the program running isn't interpreting that sequence, so it's showing up as text.